# jQuery ui autocomplete: characters show up as ??? (utf-8), adding header() stops php working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, utf-8, autocomplete

I'm trying to get jquery ui autocomplete to work with Hebrew characters (utf-8 charset).

Here's my working code - the only thing not working are the characters (autocomplete works, but ??? characters show up whenever it is a Hebrew letter) [**search.php**].

```
<?php
    // <-- this is where I add the header() quoted below
    $conn = mysql_connect("host", "user", "pass")  or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("user", $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $q = mb_strtolower(($_GET["term"]),'UTF-8');
    $return = array();
    $query = mysql_query("select * from WORDS where LABEL like '%$q%' or DESCRIPTION like '%$q%' or OTHER like '%$q%'") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        array_push($return,array('label'=>$row['LABEL'],
                                'value'=>$row['LABEL'],
                                'description'=>$row['DESCRIPTION'],
                                'other'=>$row['OTHER']));
    }
    echo(json_encode($return));
?>
```

I have read many similar stackoverflow questions, which all pointed to me having to add the line at the **top of the php** file:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
```

or

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

**both of which make my php stop working completely** (nothing works, nothing shows up in the autocomplete).

I've saved both my **php** and **html** files as utf-8 supported (and made sure the characters dont show up as ??? when I type them into the actual files), and added the meta utf-8 to my html as follows:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

I've also tried encoding the data as utf-8, all of which stop the php from working (nothing shows up in the autocomplete). Replacing:

```
$row['DESCRIPTION']
```

with

```
mb_convert_encoding($row['DESCRIPTION'], 'UTF-8');
```

However, nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have u tried functions like utf8_encode (decode) ? (in your json_encode function) it depends on the charset of your database too

Comment: `echo(json_encode(utf8_encode($return)));` also stops the php working (if this is what you meant?). The appropriate fields' collations are set to `utf8_general_ci` in my *phpMyAdmin* sql database, and the letters show up correctly in the database.

Answer (score 3):

After messing around, I finally fount the solution. Adding this line in the php file after conneting to the database did the trick!:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn);
```